# Map new column name to a data frame in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, etl

I have a list of column names like this:

```py
column_labels = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

and a data:

```
data = [df['ts'],t.dt.hour,t.dt.day, t.dt.week, t.dt.month, t.dt.year,t.dt.weekday]
```

I need to make a data frame so column_labels will be a column name for each value in the data. I understand that I need to first build a dictionary and then convert it to a data frame.  Can anyone help me with a Pandas syntax for this challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(column_labels, data)))
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!